# Unreal Engine 4 distorts some textures on import

Tags: textures, unreal-engine4

For some reason UE4 is absolutely destroying some textures that I import, specifically, a channel packed RGBA png exported from Substance Painter with  AO and some Masks in it. Every texture channel but the alpha channel shows blocky texture artifacts that kind of look like Substance Painter's padding, but applied over the entire texture, making it unusable. However the normal maps that I exported at the same time import fine.

[This is how the green channel is supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LM77.jpg)

[This is what the green channel looks like in UE4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dIlj.jpg)

I have tried reimporting the textures multiple times and have tried changing the compression settings, nothing seems to help.

I am using Unreal Engine 4.20.1 with the Substance and Destruction Plugins enabled. I am working on mid 2015 iMac running MacOS 10.13.6, the textures were exported from Substance Painter 2018.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

For displacement , roughness, metalic and spec maps , set it to linear color and keep alpha. I think that how it should  "Disable sRGB flag" from image setting inside unreal engine

[Substance To Unreal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm6CB.png)